# Missing icons in Glimpse

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, glimpse

I have just installed Glimpse, and in Google Chrome I am missing a lot of the UI icons (eg, the '+' signs to expand the blocks of details).

Any known fixes?  I use Chrome for development as I find it runs faster than FireFox and IE, so it is a bore to guess where the icons are.

Also, no close button for the debugger, and the eye doesn't show when 'minimized'.

Comment: It would be helpful as well if you told us what version of glimpse you were using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@awrigley What version of chrome are you using (currently we have been testing against Chrome 11, Firefox 4 and IE9)?

Also can you navigate to www.yoursite.com/Glimpse/glimpseSprite.png? If you can get to that endpoint can you "Inspect Element" on where you expect the buttons to be and check what chrome thinks the image URL(...) in the style is set to.